# Hue web UI not loading in different port

Tags: linux, hadoop, admin, hue

I have configured my hue in 8888 port. Now I want to switch it to 8000 port. I made the necessary changes in hue.ini file and restarted hue. However,hue is not reading the  port number:8000 in hue.ini and still it runs on default port (8888).
I made some changes to hue.ini (added some parameters to app_blacklist) and checked .the changes were reflecting in hue UI.

The problem is only with the port change.

Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: I started hue and did a netstat. netstat on 8000 returned nothing and it is listening on 8888.

Comment: Did you start Hue with supervisor or runcpserver command?

Comment: Hi Romain..Thanks for your response..This issue is fixed...There were multiple hue.ini(old and new) files in conf directory and I learned that all .ini files are treated equally. I changed the port in both the .ini files and it worked.Later ensured that there is only one hue.ini in conf directory.
Any further more inputs/corrections from your side are much appreciated.